# Optimizing speed of uploading photo using PHP

Tags: php, image, upload, compression, resize-image

I'm looking to optimize the PHP side of an app I have. The user takes a photo and then it is submitted along with other data.

If the user does not submit a photo, the page is processed in a little over two seconds. When a photo is taken, the page takes roughly 20 seconds to load (if not more).

Upload_file is the file being passed from the app. This delay happens for both iOS and Android versions.

Please let me know if you can see any places I can increase the speed of this. Thanks!

```
<?php

$tmpname = $_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"];
//Resize the image and save
$cmd = "$tmpname -scale 1000 @ ";
exec("convert $cmd $tmpname");

$uploadname = $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"];
$uploadnamex = explode(".", $uploadname);

$target_filepath = date("Y") . date("m") . date("d") . time() . $uploadnamex[0] . ".jpg";

 if (is_uploaded_file ($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"]))

 {
        $target_file = "./Photos/".$target_filepath;

         if(move_uploaded_file ($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
             echo "$target_filepath";
         else
             echo "Could not reach server. Please try again.";

 }
 else
 {
     echo "Could not reach server. Please try again.";
 }

?>
```

Comment: Kind of depends on the internet connection of the user, and your server.

Comment: Do you get the delay on a desktop machine with a good connection? What sort of host do you have - shared/VPS/dedicated? What speed connection is it on?

Comment: It's currently tied into a godaddy shared hosting account. There is no preference for using this or another one just for file upload/storage, preferably cheap though. I get roughly the same delay on my computer. Some users time out on their phones which leads me to believe I need to upgrade the server but I also want to optimize my code.